# I want logo and navbar on image carousal. Its working great, but horizontal scrollbar is getting added for no reason

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added logo and navbar inside container and carousal inside a row. Everything is fine but horizontal scrollbar is appearing. I can't figure out how?

```
 <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container logo-and-menu">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <div class="logo-img">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-menu">
                        <nav class="nav navbar-default">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <!--navbar header goes here-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="sgias-navbar">
                                    <!-- menu goes here -->
                                </div>
                            </div><!--container ends-->
                        </nav>
                    </div> <!--main-menu container ends-->
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row image-carousal">
                <div class="main-carousal ">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- main-carousal ends -->
            </div><!-- image-carousal ends -->
        </body>
```

Comment: Are you able to post your CSS for this container?

Comment: In css there is nothing. for logo and menu i have added position:absolute and z-index:1. And for carousal z-index:-1. Even if the carousal width is reduced problem still persists.

Comment: Hmm..  can you open up dev tools and see what the padding properties are for `.nav navbar-default`?  Somewhere there is content that is overflowing or something is using a negative margin...maybe.

Comment: Also, you could try setting `overflow: visible` on your parent container (in this case, `.container`) and see what results you get.